# "double free detected in tcache 2"

Tags: c, crash, free, double-free

I writed this code.
Every letter got by getchar coming into a sequence of instances of structs... Than I make it free.
Three scenario of work:

1. I press only Enter so the sequence is empty. Everything's fine.
2. I write line by line, and everything's fine
3. But somehow if I writed a non-empty line (like in sc.2) and then I just press Enter (like in sc.1) I got this error and app's crash:

   free(): double free detected in tcache 2

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct foo {

        char c;

        struct foo* p;

    };

    struct foo* set_foo()
    {

        char c;

        struct foo* f;
        struct foo* sf;

        if ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
            f = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
            f->c = c;
            sf = f;

            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
                f->p = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
                f->p->c = c;
                f = f->p;
            }
        }

        return sf;
    }

    void free_foo(struct foo* f)
    {

        struct foo* sf;
        while (f != NULL) {
            sf = f;
            f = f->p;
            if (sf != NULL) {
                free(sf);
            }
        }
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {

        while (1) {
            struct foo* f;

            f = set_foo();

            free_foo(f);
        }

        return 0;
    }
   ```

Why double free. I even check it by comparing with NULL and free() only when it's not NULL.

Comment: One observation: EOF is NOT a `char` value; it is an `int`... In `set_foo()`, change `char c;` to `int c;`...

Comment: @Fe2O3 It didn't help at all

Comment: Try setting all those pointers to NULL when they are defined... There appear to be paths that would return uninitialised values as pointers... (Bizarre code, so tricky...) Rule: ALWAYS give variables a value when they are defined. Otherwise, UB will find you and trip you up...

Comment: After `f = f->p;` in `set_foo` add `f->p = NULL;` so the last pointer isn't uninitialized. Consider adding a function like `make_foo` that allocates a struct and initializes all of the members to sane values then returns that pointer.

Comment: @Fe2O3 It helped! (setting NULL to "struct foo* sf") but why?

Comment: As pointed  out by @RetiredNinja, even the 'chaining' of nodes was flawed. Uninitialised variables are the cause of too many SO questions... I recommend favouring `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` for this reason. Then one is assured that code that worked (or not) on Tuesday will perform the same way on Wednesday...